# iOS autolayout with resize

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have two views one is textView and below it is a scrollview, in my application the textView should toggle expand when touch it.I set the "Top Space to: Text View" for scrollView in IB.But When I expand the textView it seems not work.

here is the toggle expand code.

```
- (void)onTextViewClicked:(id)sender
{
    CGRect targetFrame = _descTextView.frame;
    if (_isTextViewExpand) {
        targetFrame.size.height = _descTextViewNormalHeight;
        _descTextView.frame = targetFrame;
        _isTextViewExpand = NO;
        [_contentScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.f, kContentScrollViewDefaultHeight)];
    }
    else {
        targetFrame.size.height = _descTextViewExpandHeight;
        _descTextView.frame = targetFrame;
        _isTextViewExpand = YES;
        [_contentScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.f, kContentScrollViewDefaultHeight + ( _descTextViewExpandHeight - _descTextViewNormalHeight ))];
    }
}
```

Comment: question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

You need a different approach entirely. With Auto Layout, you should never call `-setFrame:`. If you want the views to grow you should add a constraint or edit one of the existing constraints and then call either `-setNeedsUpdateConstraints` or `-layoutIfNeeded`.

Or just turn off Auto Layout.